# Throttle redraw requests fired from pointer events

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, event-handling

I am working on a photo editor, which displays a preview to the user on a canvas. At various points in the app, the user may use sliders to adjust properties of the photo, such as scaling, rotation, etc. The preview needs to be updated in real time, as the user drags the slider.

As I understand, pointer events are fired much more rapidly than the browser window is repainted. Because of this, it would be wasteful to update the preview directly from the pointer event handlers, since most of those updates would have no visible effect. Instead, I wanted to separate the actions of updating the preview state based on the most recent pointer event, and redrawing the preview based on the latest update since the last redraw.

To this end, I wrote a small helper function called `throttleRedraw()`, which I'd appreciate if you could review. Is it properly optimized? Is it even necessary? There's probably a library for it, but I wanted to make sure I understand the principle at the core.

Here's a snippet containing the function itself, and a simple example that draws a rectangle on a canvas when you click and drag with the pointer:

```js
function throttleRedraw(target, props) {
  const {
    onstart,
    onmove,
    onend,
    ondraw,
    absolute,
  } = props;

  let frameReq = 0;
  let lastX = 0;
  let lastY = 0;
  let isTouch = false;
  let enabled = true;

  // This is the callback we will be passing to requestAnimationFrame().
  // It's just a proxy for the ondraw() function passed in the props object.
  const frameHandler = (now) => {
    if (ondraw) ondraw(now);
    frameReq = 0;
  };

  // The callback for the mousemove/touchmove events,
  // which in turn calls props.onmove() if it was specified.
  // If props.absolute is true, props.onmove() receives the x and y coordinates of the pointer;
  // otherwise, it receives the delta since the last update.
  const moveHandler = (event) => {
    if (onmove) {
      const newX = isTouch ? event.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
      const newY = isTouch ? event.touches[0].clientY : event.clientY;
      onmove(
        absolute ? newX : newX - lastX,
        absolute ? newY : newY - lastY,
        event
      );
      lastX = newX;
      lastY = newY;
    }

    // If we have not yet requested an animation frame since the last, do it now.
    if (!frameReq) {
      frameReq = window.requestAnimationFrame(frameHandler);
    }
  };

  // The callback for the mouseup/touchend events,
  // which in turn calls props.onend() if it was specified.
  const upHandler = (event) => {
    if (onend) onend(event);
    
    // Remove the event handlers we set at the start.
    if (!isTouch) {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', upHandler);
    }
    else {
      window.removeEventListener('touchmove', moveHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', upHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('touchcancel', upHandler);
    }
  };

  // Set the mousedown/touchstart event listeners on the target.
  // They're mostly the same, except for how the coordinates are obtained
  // from the event, and what additional event handlers need to be set.

  target.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    if (!enabled) return true;

    isTouch = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    lastX = event.clientX;
    lastY = event.clientY;
    if (onstart) onstart(lastX, lastY, event);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', upHandler);
  });

  target.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    if (!enabled) return true;

    isTouch = true;
    event.preventDefault();
    lastX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    lastY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    if (onstart) onstart(lastX, lastY, event);

    window.addEventListener('touchmove', moveHandler);
    window.addEventListener('touchend', upHandler);
    window.addEventListener('touchcancel', upHandler);
  });

  // Return an object that allows us to enable or disable listening for events,
  // and query the current enabled state.
  return {
    isEnabled: () => enabled,
    enable: (value) => { enabled = value; },
  };
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let x0, y0, x1, y1;

throttleRedraw(canvas, {
  absolute: true,

  onstart: (x, y) => {
    x0 = x - rect.left;
    y0 = y - rect.top;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  },
  onmove: (x, y) => {
    x1 = x - rect.left;
    y1 = y - rect.top;
  },
  ondraw: () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(
      Math.min(x0, x1),
      Math.min(y0, y1),
      Math.abs(x1 - x0),
      Math.abs(y1 - y0)
    );
  },
});
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" style="border: 2px solid #888"></canvas>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Limiting updates

You are correct about mouse event rates, I have seen mouse event 2ms apart. However touch events seem to be in sync with the display 60FPS, I have never seen a touch event fire at rates higher than this (but that is a hardware attribute as far as I know).

But that is besides the point. It is always a good idea to decouple the rendering from random events, be they user input, or from some other source. The display is driven at a fixed rate and to maintain good quality animations and presentation, keeping it tightly synced to that rate is important.

### Some style a code points.

- `window` is the default object you don't need to use it. `window.removeEventListener` is the same as `removeEventListener` and conversely your function `throttleRedraw` is the same as `window.throttleRedraw`
- It is not good to have statement block without delimiting parenthesis  as it can easily be missed when making modifications. `if (ondraw) ondraw(now);` is better as `if (ondraw) { ondraw(now) }` the `;` is optional as the line has ended in a `}`
- You don't have to have a separate event handler for each event type. Many of the event properties are repeated and you end up duplicating code. Create a single handler that handles all the events of similar type.
- The DOM does it all, but the DOM does it badly, adding and removing event handlers is just adding more work to the DOM and can be more efficiently handled by your JavaScript. Set handlers once and ignore events not needed
- Too many comments. Comment only code that is not self evident; any other comments are just noise and make the code harder to read.

### Design

From a design point I would not tie the mouse/touch event handlers so tightly with the rendering functionality. It is likely that there will be additional event like sources that require updated rendering. Completely decoupling the rendering from the pointer like events will make the system more flexible.

Touch and mouse are abstractly the same, try to reduce the individual abstraction and use a common pointer like abstract to name and define behaviors.

The flag `absolute` is an over complication. Just keep a pointer delta that contains the relative pointer motion and let the handling code pick which to use.

### Example

The example decouples the pointer from the rendering.

The pointer is created and listens to all relevant events and sets its properties `x`, `y`, `down`... and so on. The pointer also correct the coords to be relative to the target top left.

The render start up and creates a pointer object setting its target to the `canvas` The main loop continues to run and will only update if there is a change to the pointer.

The result is that the rendering becomes more complex, but that is offset by greatly reducing the pointer event handling code.

This also means that you could add keyboard events, or have running animations (like selection box dash movement) and not be reliant on the mouse event handler to pass appropriate render calls

**Note** that it listens to `document` events and filters out events not triggered by the active element. (THE snippet has modified behavior and does not allow event outside the snippet window. The event handler has the target test commented out to improve it a little, but it is not an accurate representation of how it works on an independent page).

```js
function createPointer(target) {
    var currentTarget;
    var bounds;
    const types = {
        mouse: 1, touch: 2, move: 1, up: 2, end: 2, cancel: 2, start: 0, down: 0,
        names : "touchcancel,touchend,touchmove,touchstart,mousemove,mousedown,mouseup".split(","),
    }
    const pointer = {
        delta: {x : 0, y : 0},
        pos:   {x : 0, y : 0, coord(x,y) { this.x = x; this.y = y }},
        last:  {x : 0, y : 0, set from(src) { this.x = src.x; this.y = src.y }},
        down : false,
        active : false,
        changed : false,
        set position(coord) {
            pointer.last.from = pointer.pos;
            pointer.pos.coord(coord.clientX- bounds.left + scrollX, coord.clientY - bounds.top + scrollY);
            pointer.delta.x = pointer.pos.x - pointer.last.x;
            pointer.delta.y = pointer.pos.y - pointer.last.y;
        },
        set target(element){
            if(!element){
                types.names.forEach(event => removeEventListener(event, events) );
                currentTarget = undefined;
                pointer.active = false;
            }else {
                if (!currentTarget) { types.names.forEach(event => addEventListener(event, events) ) }
                currentTarget = element;
                bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect()
                pointer.active = true;
            }
            pointer.down = false;
            pointer.changed = true;
        }
    }
    const events = event => {
       // if (event.target === currentTarget) {
            const type = types[event.type.substring(5)];
            pointer.position = types[event.type.substring(0,5)] === types.touch ? event.touches[0] : event;
            if (type === types.down) {  pointer.down = true }
            else if (type === types.up) { pointer.down = false }
            pointer.changed = true;
            event.preventDefault();
      //  }
    }
    pointer.target = target;
    return pointer;
}


const rendering = (()=> {
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const pointer = createPointer(canvas);
    var update = false;
    
    function as(src) {  this.x = src.x; this.y = src.y }
    const drag = {
        active : false,
        start : {x : 0, y : 0, as},
        end : {x : 0, y : 0, as},
        draw() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(
                Math.min(drag.start.x, drag.end.x), Math.min(drag.start.y, drag.end.y),
                Math.abs(drag.start.x - drag.end.x), Math.abs(drag.start.y - drag.end.y),
            )
        }
    }
    
    function checkPointer() {
        if (pointer.changed) {
            if (pointer.down) {
                if (!drag.active) {
                    drag.start.as(pointer.pos);
                    drag.active = true;
                }
                drag.end.as(pointer.pos);
                update = true;
            } else if (drag.active) {
                drag.end.as(pointer.pos);
                drag.active = false;
                update = true;
            }
            pointer.changed = false;
        }
    }
    
    function mainLoop(time) {
        checkPointer();
        if (update) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            drag.draw();
            update = false;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
})();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" style="border: 2px solid #888"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just a quick reply at first glance: *"Mouse events on a element have the annoying habit of only hearing events while the mouse is over the element."* -- That's actually why I used `window.addEventListener`, to capture the move/up/cancel events at the highest stage of propagation. `document` can still be a problem if the page doesn't fill the whole window. I'll look through your example in more detail when I'm not on my phone. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MátéSafranka You are absolutely correct, I ran you code and at the time forgot that the snippets messed with the mouse event, and I just presumed. Will change the answer.